# Navigate to a fragment from another graph without it being the start destination

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

In my first graph, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/firstGraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/listFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ListFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_list_to_details"
            app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.DetailsFragment">

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

In my second graph I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/secondGraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/firstGraph" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="com.example.DashboardFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboard_to_notification"
            app:destination="@id/notificationFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notificationFragment"
        android:name="com.example.NotificationsFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notification_to_details"
            app:destination="@id/firstGraph"/>

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I want to navigate from "notificationFragment" to "detailsFragment" directly without it being the start destination, with including the second graph stack

Comment: I have this same problem. I thought about removing the nested graphs (at the cost of a mess), but even that I can't do because I'm using view models shared by a graph context.

Comment: I had previously managed to make it work by creating a "temp" dest as start of a graph which receives a parameter that it reads and uses to re-navigate - popping itself. This works, but then it breaks shared element transition animations.

Comment: I temporarily solved it by duplicating the graphs, I probably shared your opinion to decide not to use it, but it's looked pretty navigation method just like storyboards in iOS

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As per the [nested graph documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph#nested_graphs):

> [Nested graphs] also provide a level of encapsulation — destinations outside of the nested graph do not have direct access to any of the destinations within the nested graph.

There is one exception to that, when you are [navigating using a URI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri), effectively deep linking into **any** destination:

> Unlike navigation using action or destination IDs, you can navigate to any URI in your graph, regardless of whether the destination is visible. You can navigate to a destination on the current graph or a destination on a completely different graph.

Therefore you can [add an implicit deep link to your graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
    android:name="com.example.DetailsFragment">
    <deepLink app:uri="android-app://your.package.name/details" />
</fragment>
```

Then navigate to that destination via URI:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("android-app://your.package.name/details")
navController.navigate(uri)
```

It doesn't matter what your URI is, as long as the `<deepLink>` and what you pass to `navigate` match. Any arguments you have would need to be encoded in the URL.

Comment: This seems promising, but I'd say it would get weird when the argument is an object - because then I'd have to break the object properties and pass one by one in the URL.

Comment: Also, the deeplink creates the backstack: _"When nesting graphs, the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each <navigation> element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack."_. So, this could cause some weird behavior where the user sees a screen for which they haven't been to.

Comment: Wonderfull answer!! Thank you, But I think it's not complete. As @FirstOne said: It's missed the destination fragment stack problem, one more thing; what if I would pass a serialized (or Parcelable) object as a parameter. it seems it needs a workaround to pass the parameters

Comment: @FirstOne - navigating by URI does not add any synthetic back stack destinations. That's what the line `When navigating using URI, the back stack is not reset. This is unlike other deep link navigation, where the back stack is replaced when navigating.` means in that documentation.

Comment: @AhmadAlselwadi - yes, that's exactly what I meant when I specifically said `Any arguments you have would need to be encoded in the URL.`

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you very much for your answer and clarifications, I tried a few workarounds like replacing graphs at run time but unfortunately, I lost the previous graph navigation, also I tried to add the details fragment to the first graph as a new destination and also could get the second graph navigation

Comment: @AhmadAlselwadi - yes, navigating by URI is the only mechanism that works.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ok.. I'll see if I can test it later. The only problem then is passing arguments to the destination. Adding them to the URL seems like it could become a mess.

Comment: @FirstOne - think about if you were building a website. Would you encode your information in the URL directly or would you have a common repository for the information and only pass an identifier in your URL? Same problem here (and the same recommendation: just pass an identifier)

Comment: Too bad there is no other way. Some screens were just "plug and play" with required input and some output. Well, I guess I have a lot of work to do.. @ianhanniballake

Comment: @FirstOne - given that arguments count against the limited amount of data you can put in saved instance state (or face a `TransactionTooLargeException`, particularly since newer versions of Android lower that limit even more so), passing an identifier is a better way of doing things in all cases, not just this particular one.

Comment: Thank you again @ianhanniballake, it's a wonderful answer, but seems no way to have  all of the second graph stack (the only solution worked for me is create another duplicated stack included the needed destinations)

Comment: @ianhanniballake what is the downside of just using global action for this, besides breaking of the encapsulation?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can you please provide a similar solution for Jetpack Compose also in case of Bottom Tab ? How to navigate to nested composable in other graph and pressing back it should retain previous tab state ?