# How to navigate to specific fragment of second_graph from first nav_graph?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a Ordering Fragment where use click apply order button, and then if user is not logged-in we navigate to login_nav_graph. After success login I open main_nav_graph but it opens it with HomeFragment because it is root. So, how can I open after succesfull login open OrderingFragment which is in main_nav_graph ?

Comment: check this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985632/navigate-to-a-fragment-from-another-graph-without-it-being-the-start-destination

Answer (score 0):

Suppose below is your navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_main_nav">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_main_nav"
    android:name="com.MainNavFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_main_nav"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_nav" />
```

so in  app:startDestination= remove "@+id/navigation_home" and add "@+id/navigation_main_nav" so after success login it's open main_nav_graph